# display different content using bootstrap modals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to make a content with different categorized photo, when I click one of the category ,it will pop up a modal(which is I'm using bootstrap) contain pictures from that category.For example: I have two category, male and female. When I click Male category, it will pop up a modal with all male photo only. This is the source code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">



                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="..." alt="...">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="..." alt="...">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                            ...
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- Controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>


                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to post a fiddle showing what you have so far.

Comment: You can do like inside the modal-body you can have all the categories added and using ng-if or ng-show/hide based on the selected category you can show the content inside the modal.